# Chunked base64 string, piece by piece using http nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, base64

From my API(nodejs), I'm accessing a third-party API (using http) to download files.
The service returns a Base64 string, chopped into smaller pieces, to be able to handle larger files.

Is it possible to do multiple http-requests (loop ?) to the third-party service, send each piece in response, to the browser until there is no longer any response from the third-party service?

The reason i want to do this, is because I don't want to consume to much memory on the node server.

I will put the pieces back together in the browser.

Any suggestions on how to do this? 
See my current code below.

```
var request = require('request');
 router.post('/getfiledata', function(req, res) {

        var fileid = req.body.fileid;
        var token = req.headers.authorization;

        getFileData(req, res, dbconfig, fileid, token, function(err, chunkOfFile) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send({
                    status: 500,
                    message: err
                });
                return;
            }
            res.send(chunkOfFile);
        });
});

function getFileData(req, res, dbconfig, fileid, token, next) {

var url ="http://*ip*/service/rest/getfiledata";

var reqbody = {
    fileId: fileid
};

var options = {
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': token
    },
    json: true,
    body: reqbody
};

/*SOME LOOP HERE TO GET EACH CHUNK AND SEND TO BROWSER*/
    request(options, function(err, resp, body) {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            next(err, undefined);
            return;

        } else {
            next(undefined, body)
        };
    });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) to push chunks to the browser.

Server :

```
socket.send("chunk", chunkOfFile)
```

Client :

```
let fullString = ""
socket.on("chunk", chunkOfFile => fullString += chunkOfFile )
```

Something like that

Answer (score 0):

The `request` library you are using allows for streaming of data from one source to another. Check out the documentation on [github](https://github.com/request/request#streaming).
Here is an example from that page:

```
request
  .get(source)
  .on('response', function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode) // 200
    console.log(response.headers['content-type']) // 'image/png'
  })
  .pipe(request.put(destination))
```

You may choose to use the `http` module from Nodejs, as it implements the [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_events) class too.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a recursive loop from the client. Sending http-requests to my API(node) until the response no longer returns any base64 data chunks.

Thank you guys!